# AutoMapper how to set a destination member based on many Source Members?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I just cannot figure out how this works in practice.

Basically I have a ProductState in my DTO that looks like this:

```
public class ProductState
{
    public static ProductState OutOfService => new(1, "Out of Service", "bg-secondary");
    public static ProductState InService => new(2, "In Service", "bg-sucess");
    public static ProductState Repair => new(3, "Repair","bg-dark");
    public static ProductState Damaged => new(4, "Damaged","bg-warning text-dark");
    public static ProductState Scrapped => new(5, "Scrapped", "badge-danger");
    public static ProductState CheckedOut => new(6, "Checked Out", "bg-primary");

    public ProductState (int id, string name, string css)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        CSS = css;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CSS { get; set; }
}
```

I have the DTO ProductDTO which looks like this ( I stripped out all members other than one I am having issue with ProductState):

```
public class ViewProductDto : BaseProductDto, IProductPartialDto
{
    public ProductState State { get; set; }
}
```

I have an entity model which I have cut down to the following members which I need to determine the Product State:

```
public class Product 
{
    public bool? IsDamaged { get; set; }
    public bool? IsScrapped { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WhenScrapped {get;set;}
    public List<InOut> Inout {get;set;}
    
}
```

within my startup.cs I have registed the following:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
        {
            config.AddProfile(new ViewProductMapper());
            
        }, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

The Auto Mapper Profile looks like this:

```
public class ViewProductMapper : Profile
{
    public ViewProductMapper()
    {
        
        CreateMap<Product, ViewProductDto>()
       

        .ForMember(dest => dest.State, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(o=> MapProductState(o)))



    }
    private ProductState MapProductState(Product eqp)
    {
        if ((eqp.IsBeingScrapped.HasValue && eqp.IsBeingScrapped.Value) || eqp.ScrappedWhen.HasValue)
        {
            return ProductState.Scrapped;
        }
        else if ((eqp.IsDamage.HasValue && eqp.IsDamage.Value) && !((eqp.IsBeingScrapped.HasValue && eqp.IsBeingScrapped.Value) || eqp.ScrappedWhen.HasValue))
        {
            return ProductState.Damaged;
        }
        else if (eqp.Inout != null && eqp.Inout.Any(a => a.Out))
        {
            return ProductState.CheckedOut;
        }
        else
        {
            return ProductState.InService;
        }
    }

}
```

Whenever I run

```
_mapper.Map<List<Product>, List<ViewDto>>(products)
```

all other members map successfully but the state one is always null.

Can anyone suggest if I am doing this right?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu not sure how this helps.  I have automapper working its just not mapping that one member.  I can see my profile in automapper it just ignoring my productstate config

Comment: Your config doesn't make much sense to me. Try it without DI. If that works, then you're on to smth.

Comment: Should that be `_mapper.Map<List<Product>, List<ViewProductDto>>(products)` instead of `ViewDto` showing in your code?